# SSH into Raspberry Pi Running Ubuntu 22.04 Server LTS

Tags: ubuntu

I managed to flash Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server on a 32 GB SD card using RasPi Imager where I also configured my WLAN. I then connect the RasPi's Micro USB to the USB port of my Linux machine and I was hoping that I could log in, but for some reason I do not see my RasPi listed on my router.

Is there an idea on how I could find the host of my RasPi so that I can SSH into it? I also do not have an external monitor to connect my RasPi to. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I solved it.

1. I inserted the SD card (after flashing the OS image on it) in my computer
2. I opened the boot partition and added an empty file called ssh
3. I connected my Raspberry Pi via an Ethernet cable to my home router
4. Find WiFi card name

   ```
   $ ls /sys/class/net
   eth0  lo  wlan0
   ```
5. Edit the network configuration file:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
   ```

> ```
> # This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
> # to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
> # network configuration capabilities, write a file
> # /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
> # network: {config: disabled}
> network:
>     version: 2
>     wifis:
>         renderer: networkd
>         wlan0:
>             access-points:
>                 MySSID:
>                     password: MyPassWord
>             dhcp4: true
>             optional: true
> ```

6. Update MySSID and MyPassword with my WiFi connections and then reboot.